# How do I get the option values while looping through a simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, csv

I've got a php script that reads an xml file and loops through the values and asigns them to variables that I later use to make a csv file.

It's working great upto a point. One of the items in the xml is options, the problem I have is that there's a load of different option types. I've put a sample of the code I'm using below and it works ok when I know what the options are but unfortunately sometimes the options have different spellings or are new options, so I need to read the options first then write them and their values to a variable.

Here's what I've been doing, with an example reading the Size option.

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xml_url);

foreach($xml->item as $_item){
 //Get The Item SKU
    $sku = $_item->sku;

 //Loop through the sizes and assign them to $size[$i]  
$i=0;
foreach($_item->options->Size as $_size){
        $size[$i++] = $_size;
        }

$fopt = fopen('options.csv', 'a');      
if (isset($size))   {
foreach($size as $s){
    $thisline = $sku . '`Size:Select`' . $s . '`12' . "\n";
    fwrite($fopt, $thisline);
                    }
        unset($size);       
                }       
}
```

The $thisline variable in the code above is the layout the csv needs, with the exception that when there's more than one option per item the second field would look something like '`Size:Select,Color:Select`'

So what I need to do is loop through the options, if there's any, find out what they are and write them to the `$thisline` variable with their values.

Below is a sample of the layout of the xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0">
<root>
    <item>
        <sku>63344</sku>
        <weight>0.0100</weight>
        <Price>29.99</Price>
        <url>http://www.clothing.com</url>
        <name>Mens Jacket</name>
        <category>
            <parent_id>123</parent_id>
            <parent_name>Clothes</parent_name>
            <category_id>234</category_id>
            <category_name>Jackets</category_name>
        </category>
        <media>
            <image>jpg1</image>
            <image>jpg2</image>
        </media>
        <options>
            <Size>32</Size>
            <Size>34</Size>
            <Size>36</Size>
            <Size>38</Size>
            <Color>Red</Color>
            <Color>Blue</Color>
        </options>
        <short_description>Short description here</short_description>
        <description>Longer Description Here</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>62211</sku>
        <weight>0.0100</weight>
        <Price>39.99</Price>
        <url>http://www.clothing.com</url>
        <name>Mens Trousers</name>
        <category>
            <parent_id>123</parent_id>
            <parent_name>Clothes</parent_name>
            <category_id>234</category_id>
            <category_name>Trousers</category_name>
        </category>
        <media>
            <image>jpg5</image>
            <image>jpg7</image>
        </media>
        <options>
            <Trouser_Size>28</Trouser_Size>
            <Trouser_Size>30</Trouser_Size>
            <Trouser_Size>32</Trouser_Size>
            <Color>Red</Color>
            <Color>Blue</Color>
        </options>
        <short_description>Short description here</short_description>
        <description>Longer Description Here</description>
    </item>
    <item>
        <sku>22111</sku>
        <weight>0.0100</weight>
        <Price>19.99</Price>
        <url>http://www.clothing.com</url>
        <name>Mens Shirt</name>
        <category>
            <parent_id>123</parent_id>
            <parent_name>Clothes</parent_name>
            <category_id>234</category_id>
            <category_name>Shirts</category_name>
        </category>
        <media>
            <image>jpg9</image>
            <image>jpg44</image>
        </media>
        <options>
            <Button_Color>Brown</Button_Color>
            <Button_Color>Blue</Button_Color>
            <Button_Color>Green</Button_Color>
        </options>
        <short_description>Short description here</short_description>
        <description>Longer Description Here</description>
    </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this the kind of thing you're looking for?

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file( $xml_url );

$fopt = fopen( 'options.csv', 'w' ); 

foreach( $xml->item as $_item ){

    //Get The Item SKU
    $sku = $_item->sku;
    $options = array();

    // Collect all the options into a single multi-dimensional array
    foreach( $_item->options as $_thisOptionSet ) {
        foreach( $_thisOptionSet as $_thisOptionSetName => $thisOptionSetElement ) {
            $options[ $_thisOptionSetName ][] = (string) $thisOptionSetElement;
        }
    }

    // Format the output
    foreach( $options as $optionName => $optionValues ) {
        foreach(  $optionValues as $thisOptionValue ) {
            $thisline = $sku . '`'.$optionName.':Select`' . $thisOptionValue . '`12' . "\n";
            fwrite( $fopt, $thisline );
        }
    }
}
fclose( $fopt );
```

The key is the fact that you can loop over the XML nodes and key will be the index.  This allows you to group the data into distinct arrays.

Once you've done that it's easy to output the data in whatever format you're looking for.

Comment: And yes, as posted by Alexander, your xml document needs a root node.  And should really open with a statement that it's XML: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Thank you so much Rob, this is almost perfect. It's exactly what I need, the only small problem I have now is the way items with multiple different options are output. The code above loops through them as seperate lines, which should be fine but the csv import tool I use this in (prestashop) actually won't work properly like this as it requires multiple options per product to be in the same field seperated by a comma.

Comment: I've tested and the above outputs. like `123`Color:Select`red` and `123`Size:Select`32` what I need is for it to output `123`Color:Select,Size:Select`Red,32` on one line

Comment: Just to clarify, you're looking for a row in the csv for every possible combination of all options for a single item?  E.g. if you have colours red and blue and sizes 10 and 12 you'd have 4 rows, something like Colour:Select,Size:Select`Red,10` | Colour:Select,Size:Select'Red,12' | Colour:Select,Size:Select'Blue,10' | Colour:Select,Size:Select'Blue,12'

Comment: Yea Rob, that's exactly what I need, but I've been looking at it and the xml I'm currently working on only has a handful of items with multiple combinations (out of several thousand items) so I might just go with what I have and manually edit the few that need it. Thank you so much for your help, I'd have been weeks figuring out what you've done above lol.

Answer (score 0):

In xml document should be one root element. In xml file you have 2 "item" elements.

You can add a root element:

```
<itemList>
   ...You XML content here...
</itemList>
```

or remove second  element in xml file, to have well formed xml document.

Comment: Many thanks Alexander, this was just a snippet from the xml to show the structure of the <items> the actual xml does have a <root> and <?xml version="1.0">